# Sharing image on whatsapp broken after recent update on 22nd may

Tags: image, android-intent, sharing, whatsapp, universal-image-loader

I'm using Universal image loader and was able to forward images from my app to whatsapp using this code

```
public static void shareImage(Context context, File pictureFile, String text) {
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);

    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
}
```

But with the recent whatsapp update on may 22nd . I'm getting '**The file format is not supported**' toast.

[image]

Comment: So have you tried changing file formats?

Comment: mostly my app contains jpg and png . This same code used to work earlier.

Comment: Yes, and now they've apparently changed supported formats, so *you need to change too*.

Comment: yeah. Image sharing used to work without specifying the extension earlier.

Comment: So what? This is what happens with third party integrations. You can't expect your code to always keep working whatever they change.

Comment: hahah if only it did life would have been so easy ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier image sharing would work with

```
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
```

but in the latest update following changes are required for sharing image on whatsapp

```
public class ImageFileNameGenerator implements FileNameGenerator {
    @Override
    public String generate(String imageUri) {
        String extension = imageUri.substring(imageUri.lastIndexOf("."));
        return String.valueOf(imageUri.hashCode() + extension);
    }
}
```

update config

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
        .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new ImageFileNameGenerator())
        .build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

image sharing code

```
public static void shareImage(Context context, File pictureFile, String text) {
    String imagePath = pictureFile.getAbsolutePath();

    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(imagePath);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);

    String imageFileExtension = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf("."));

    shareIntent.setType("image/" + imageFileExtension);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
}
```